# React native with redux accessing hash

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm using react native with redux. The store returns a simple hash like this:

```
hash = { "1": {"questions": {'1': 'A', '2': '', '3': '', '4': '', '5': '', '6': 'A' } } }
```

The problem is that I can't access the value this way:

```
hash[1].questions['1'] // should return A
```

If the hash is created outside the store (redux) I can access normally.
How can I solve this problem ?
Thanks.

Comment: I think plain object you also can not make this work.Try hash["1"].questions["1"].It is a object not a array,you cannot use index `a number` but a "string".

Comment: hash["1"].questions doesn't work: undefined is not an object

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not really clear, are you using redux-persist? if yes, the problem could be because the object you stored is not instanceted by redux-persist, you may need to use this component:

https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist-immutable

The information restored from the redux-persist cannot be processed as an instance.